# Need to Replace in string with pentaho

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I have to replace a part of strings in fields rows. Perhaps if anybody have some knowledge about using the replace in string with pentaho.

string to replace:

[image: string to replace]

Comment: If you still need help with this, please be more clear. What's your input field? What you want to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Replace in String` step. Type the String you want to search in the `Search` field and in the `Replace with` field, you have to type the String that will replace the existing String you searched.

You can always browse to `../Pentaho/design-tools/data-integration/samples/transformations` for the examples.

Comment: Thank you for the solution suggested i appritiated

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer if it has helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to "Replace in string":

If you want to replace a **part** of a String, something you could do is use the "Strings cut" step to cut a part of a string which you want to replace, replace the value by whatever you want and then "Concat fields" to put strings together again.